Thellmund WeekView Library horizontalScrollListener
Im using this library in my project :
implementation 'com.github.thellmund.Android-Week-View:core:5.2.4'
Is there anyway to get the horizontalScrollListener when is changing the day? Im working with only one day view. I want to do a call to my api passing the current calendar day, so i need the listener.
Thanks.
I tried with diferent adapters and methods for example onRangeChange or onLoadMore.

You can just make use of the onRangeChangeListener in combination with the current visible day. The onRangeChangeListener gets called when the visible range changes, which is useful for detecting when a day shift occurs.
Here's the way you can achieve this:
    weekView.setOnRangeChangeListener { startDate, endDate ->
    // If you're only showing one day, startDate and endDate will be the same
    val currentDay = startDate

    // Call your API with the currentDay
    callYourApi(currentDay) 
}

So,
startDate and endDate represent the visible days after the scroll event.
Since you're working with a single-day view, startDate should give you the current visible day.
I've updated the answer here. This is how you can convert from Java's LocalDate to ThreeTen LocalDate.
javaLocalDate = java.time.LocalDate.now();
LocalDate threeTenLocalDate = LocalDate.of(javaLocalDate.getYear(), javaLocalDate.getMonthValue(), javaLocalDate.getDayOfMonth());


Im working with current min version 23, and methods of Java LocalDate are not supported for this version. Im using the threeten library. Is there anyway to convert the Java LocalDate to ThreeTen LocalDate? Or use methods that work with this verision?

I have edited my previous answer, you can check now how to convert Java's LocalDate to ThreeTen LocalDate. Hope this resolves your issue.
